# Securing iOS applications communication from client side

Tags: ios, session-management, protection

Many of you have heard about instagram flaw that facebook has not fixed yet,

The flaw allows the attacker to hijack the session by sniffing the session cookie on Instagram iOS app since it does not encrypt the communication,

I have been looking for a way to protect my account - say that I am famous and hackers target me :p - What would help me protect it from my side. I am not the developer, and I don't work on Facebook, so I cannot fix the flaw.

Someone would just say, do not use the iOS app and just use the browser, but that would not fix the problem as I am looking for the best solution.

Is there a way to secure the iOS apps communications? Do I need to register to a proxy server and set it on iOS, or rent a VPN? what would be the advantages and disadvantages of my solution and is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belong to a more general question which could read "what can I do, as a user, to protect myself against services that have know unpatched security flaw".

The answers aren't very nice, unfortunately.

First - and perhaps the best way to handle the issue - do not use the vulnerable service and applications. This is the best possible way because not only does it protect you against your data (identity, etc.) being stolen, it also put pressure on the provider to fix their service.

Second, try to mitigate the problem: use 2FA if it is available, don't reuse password, use the service only minimally and assume every data you place it on is going to be compromised: properly planning ahead your recovery is often half the battle.

Third, try to lower the risk of interception by using a VPN to a network connected as close as possible to the target service. Unless you can connect directly to the target network, this does not remove the vulnerability but it does force any attacker to get in the route between the end of your VPN tunnel and the target service in order to exploit it.